# Duplicating Div with For Loop

Tags: for-loop, duplicates

I'm trying to duplicate a div with a  for loop and am having NO luck. Why won't this duplicate my outerSquare?

```
var origDiv = document.getElementById("outerSquare");
    for (i=1; i<=4; ++i){
    newDiv = document.body.appendChild(origDiv.cloneNode(true));
    newDiv.setAttribute("id", "block"+i);
    newDiv.style.left = i*40 +"px";
    newDiv.style.top = i*40 +"px";
}

origDiv.style.left = "200px"; //just trying to get it out of the way
```

Here's the full stuff:
http://jsfiddle.net/dmperkins74/0so3dwot/2/

Any help appreciated! Thanks,
Dan P.

Comment: Please add tag of your programming language.